# How to stop the past timer and show only the upcoming timer in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am comparing the scheduled times with current date-time. The values for upcoming schedule time is showing correct but, when the time is already passed shows negative values. In place of that, I want to show 'Time Up'. What is the better solution to implement it.

```
const timeData = [
    {
      "start-time": "11th Mar 2021, 2:17 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "15th Mar 2021, 1:17 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "21st Mar 2021, 10:00 AM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "24th Mar 2021, 3:15 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "1st Apr 2021, 6:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "15th Apr 2021, 11:15 AM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "19th Apr 2021, 8:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "20th Apr 2021, 7:50 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "28th Apr 2021, 7:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "start-time": "2nd May 2021, 11:30 AM"
    }
  ];

  /* Code for Calculating Time Left */
  const calculateTimeLeft = () => {
    /* Formating Date and Time */

    let timeLeft = {};

    return timeLeft;
  };

  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);
  });

  /* End for Code of Calculating Time Left */

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Time Date Diff</h2>
      {timeData.map((data) => {
        const diff =
          Date.parse(
            moment(
              data["start-time"].replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1")
            ).format("YYYY M DD, h:mm A")
          ) - Date.parse(new Date());

        return (
          <h2>
            {Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))} days{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)} hours{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60)} mins{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60)} seconds
          </h2>
        );
      })}
      {/* <div>
        {timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <span>Time's up!</span>}
      </div> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sn31v

Below is the image for reference
[image]

After clicking the link, head on to timediff.js file

Comment: Map to an array of diff time, filter <= 0, then map that to React elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below before the return code in timediff.js code

```
 if (diff <= 0) {
      return <h2>Time Up</h2>;
 }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7j97v?file=/timediff.js
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        return diff > 0 ? (
            <h2>
              {Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))} days{" "}
              {Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)} hours{" "}
              {Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60)} mins{" "}
              {Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60)} seconds
            </h2>
          ) : (
            <h2>Time do be up</h2>
          );
        })}
```

instead of

```
        return (
          <h2>
            {Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))} days{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)} hours{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60)} mins{" "}
            {Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60)} seconds
          </h2>
        );
```

in `timediff.js`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Moment.js within your project you can simplify date parsing:

```js
const string = "11th Mar 2021, 2:17 PM";

// see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/
const time = moment(string, "Do MMM YYYY, h:mm A");
```

If you work with Moment.js instances you can calculate the difference in the following manner:

```js
const now = moment();
const msDiff = time.diff(now);
```

Moment.js also has helpers for durations, which can be instantiated from the difference in time.

```js
const duration = moment.duration(msDiff);
```

You can get the days, minutes, etc. easily from this duration instance.

```js
duration.days(); // returns days 0-30
duration.asDays(); // returns the duration converted to days eg. 1.337

duration.hours(); // returns hours 0-23
duration.asHours(); // returns the duration converted to hours eg. 32.088

// etc.
```

To help out with the "time is up" part, you could introduce a render function that returns early (guard claus) if the difference in time is zero or less.

```js
function renderDifference(diff) {
  if (diff <= 0) return <span>Time's up!</span>;
  // ...
}
```

With these helpers the code can be simplified quite a lot:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="time-data"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo } = React;

const format = "Do MMM YYYY, h:mm A";
function TimeData({ timeData }) {
  useRenderInterval(1000); // re-render each second, see helper below

  // convert date/time strings into moment objects
  const moments = useMemo(() => (
    timeData.map(time => moment(time["start-time"], format, true))
  ), [timeData]);
  
  // calculate the new durations each render
  const now = moment();
  const durations = moments.map(moment => moment.diff(now));
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Time Date Diff</h2>
      <ul>{durations.map(renderDuration)}</ul>
    </>
  );
}

function renderDuration(msDuration, index) {
  if (msDuration <= 0) {
    return <li key={index}>Time's up!</li>;
  }
  
  const duration = moment.duration(msDuration);
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      {Math.floor(duration.asDays())} days{" "}
      {duration.hours()} hours{" "}
      {duration.minutes()} minutes{" "}
      {duration.seconds()} seconds
    </li>
  );
}

// helper hooks
function useForceRender() {
  const [_value, setValue] = useState({});
  return () => setValue({});
}

function useRenderInterval(ms) {
  const forceRender = useForceRender();
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(forceRender, ms);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, []);
}

// data
const timeData = [
  { "start-time": "11th Mar 2021, 2:17 PM" },
  { "start-time": "15th Mar 2021, 1:17 PM" },
  { "start-time": "21st Mar 2021, 10:00 AM" },
  { "start-time": "24th Mar 2021, 3:15 PM" },
  { "start-time": "1st Apr 2021, 6:30 PM" },
  { "start-time": "15th Apr 2021, 11:15 AM" },
  { "start-time": "19th Apr 2021, 8:30 PM" },
  { "start-time": "20th Apr 2021, 7:50 PM" },
  { "start-time": "28th Apr 2021, 7:30 PM" },
  { "start-time": "2nd May 2021, 11:30 AM" },
];

// add dynamic times and reverse the array for demonstration purposes
timeData.push({ "start-time": moment().add(1, "minute").format(format) });
timeData.push({ "start-time": moment().add(2, "weeks").format(format) });
timeData.reverse();

ReactDOM.render(<TimeData timeData={timeData} />, document.querySelector("#time-data"));
</script>
```